# JBehave cannot run multiple scenarios

Tags: jbehave

I have the following story file (in portuguese):

```
Narrativa: Cadastrar peritos
Como um usuário do AUD
Desejo poder cadastrar novos peritos
De modo que eu possa referencia-los no momento da audiencia

Cenário: Acessar menu configuracao
Dado que estou na aplicacao AUD
Quando eu clico no botao Configuracao

Cenário: adicionar peritos
Dado que estou na tela de peritos
Quando informo o perito <codigo>, <nome>, <especialidade> e <cpf>

Exemplos:
br/jus/trt4/aud/stories/peritos.table
```

But for some reason jbehave is not able to run the second scenario. The output is:

```
Processing system properties {}
Using controls EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=false,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeouts=300,threads=1,failOnStoryTimeout=false]

(BeforeStories)

Running story br/jus/trt4/aud/stories/aud_stories.story

(br/jus/trt4/aud/stories/aud_stories.story)
Scenario: Narrativa: Cadastrar peritos
Como um usu?rio do AUD
Desejo poder cadastrar novos peritos
De modo que eu possa referencia-los no momento da audiencia

Cenário: Acessar menu configuracao
Examples:
Dado que estou na aplicacao AUD
Quando eu clico no botao Configuracao

Cenário: adicionar peritos
Dado que estou na tela de peritos
Quando informo o perito <codigo>, <nome>, <especialidade> e <cpf>

|codigo|nome|especialidade|cpf|
|123|luiz fernando|automacao de testes|34432|

Example: {codigo=123, nome=luiz fernando, especialidade=automacao de testes, cpf=34432}
Using timeout for story aud_stories.story of 300 secs.
Dado que estou na aplicacao AUD
Quando eu clico no botao Configuracao

Cen?rio: adicionar peritos (PENDING)
Dado que estou na tela de peritos (NOT PERFORMED)
Quando informo o perito 123, luiz fernando, automacao de testes e 34432 (NOT PERFORMED)
@When("eu clico no botao Configuracao\r\n\r\nCen\uFFFDrio: adicionar peritos")
@Pending
public void whenEuClicoNoBotaoConfiguracaoCenrioAdicionarPeritos() {
  // PENDENTE
}





(AfterStories)

Generating reports view to 'C:\Users\lestivalet\workspace\AutoHotKey\target\jbehave' using formats '[stats, console, html]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
Reports view generated with 3 stories (of which 1 pending) containing 2 scenarios (of which 1 pending)
```

Please note the line "@When("eu clico no botao Configuracao\r\n\r\nCen\uFFFDrio: adicionar peritos")" It is joining the work "Cenario" in the last sentence of the first scenario.

If I have only one scenario it worked well.

If I use english keywords it works!!

Any idea? I'm using jbehave 4.0.4 with the following configuration:

```
public class AudStories extends JUnitStory {

    public Configuration configuration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration() {
        };

        configuration.useParameterControls(new ParameterControls().useDelimiterNamedParameters(true));
        configuration.useKeywords(new LocalizedKeywords(new Locale("pt")));
        configuration.useStepFinder(new StepFinder());
        configuration.useStoryControls(new StoryControls());
        configuration.useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(configuration.keywords()));
        configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats().withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML));

        return configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new AUDSteps());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies here:

```
cenario: Narrativa: Cadastrar peritos
Como um usu?rio do AUD
Desejo poder cadastrar novos peritos
De modo que eu possa referencia-los no momento da audiencia

Cenário: Acessar menu configuracao
```

Notice that the first Scenario is being interpreted as a Narrative.  Likely your keyword translations are incomplete.  Perhaps the "In order to" needs to be defined.